# Catalan sequence problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

- For $4$ variables $g_{1}, g_{2}, g_{3}, g_{4}$ ,the sum of the expressions
  $$
  (g_1-g_2)(g_3-g_4),(g_1-g_3)(g_4-g_2),(g_1-g_4)(g_2-g_3)\quad
  \mbox{is}\quad {\large 0}
  $$
  ( known as [Euler's Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931603)). So the rank of the vector space is $2$.
- For $6$ variables, let
  \begin{align}
  & M = \left\{(g_a-g_b)(g_c-g_d)(g_e-g_f)\mid a,b,c,d,e,f\text{ is a}
  \right.
  \\[1mm] &
  \left.\text{permutation of
  1,2,3,4,5,6, and }a < b,c < d,e < f\right\}
  \end{align}
  It is easy to check by hand that the rank of $M$ is $5$.
- For $8,10$ variables, the rank is $14, 42$ respectively.
  ( I found it using $\tt Mathematica$).
- For $2n$ variables, I guess the rank is the $\left(n + 1\right)$th *Catalan Number*. Is that right?

Comment: The expansion of $(1-8x+21x^2-20x^3+5x^4)/(1-9x+28x^2-35x^3+15x^4-x^5)$ also produces $1,1,2,5,14,42$ as Catalan, but then $132,429$, which is not Catalan. Also $binomial(fibonacci(k) + 1, 2)$ produces $1,1,2,5,14,42,132$ and so on.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The first example you gave only starts failing at the $x^{10}$ term. $132$ and $429$, as well as the two terms that follow $1430$ and $4862$, *are* Catalan numbers. The second example evaluates to $3$ when $k=3$. Though I do get your point that it's best not to be too confident about integer sequences when you only know the first few terms.

Comment: For 6 variables how did you "check by hand" the rank?

Comment: For 6 variables, if a factor $(x_i-x_j)$ appears three times, it can be removed (because the remaining 4 elements appear three times, so linearly dependent). We start with\begin{array}c(g_1-g_2)(g_3-g_4)(g_5-g_6)\\ (g_1-g_3)(g_2-g_4)(g_5-g_6)\\ (g_1-g_3)(g_2-g_5)(g_6-g_4)\\ (g_1-g_4)(g_2-g_5)(g_6-g_3)\\ (g_1-g_5)(g_2-g_3)(g_4-g_6)\\ (g_1-g_5)(g_2-g_4)(g_6-g_3)\\ (g_1-g_6)(g_2-g_3)(g_4-g_5)\end{array}

Comment: We have a linearly independent set\begin{array}l(g_1-g_2)(g_3-g_4)(g_5-g_6)\\ (g_1-g_3)(g_2-g_4)(g_5-g_6)\\ (g_1-g_3)(g_2-g_5)(g_6-g_4)\\ (g_1-g_4)(g_2-g_5)(g_6-g_3)\\ (g_1-g_5)(g_2-g_3)(g_4-g_6)\end{array}
So rank is 5.

Comment: Because\begin{array}l(g_ 1-g_ 2)(g_ 3-g_ 4)(g_ 5-g_ 6)+(g_ 1-g_ 5)(g_ 2-g_ 3)(g_ 4-g_ 6)\\=(g_ 1-g_ 3)(g_ 2-g_ 4)(g_ 5-g_ 6)  +(g_ 1-g_ 6)(g_ 2-g_ 3)(g_ 4-g_ 5)\\=-(g_ 1-g_ 3)(g_ 2-g_ 5)(g_ 6-g_ 4) +(g_ 1-g_ 4)(g_ 2-g_ 5)(g_ 6-g_3)-(g_ 1-g_ 5)(g_ 2-g_ 4)(g_ 6-g_ 3)\end{array}